# How to describe a linear graph with some jumps

Tags: graphing-functions

To describe this simple with a little pseudocode (i'm better with software than mathematical notation, sorry):

```
f(x) = if (x <= 50%) then 0 else 1
```

This with a graph:

```
 100% |            x     x
  50% |
   0% | x   x      
      |___________________
        0%  33%   66%  100%
```

How would you describe this graph?

I'm trying to find the words to distinguish it from a flat linear graph:

```
 100% |
  50% | x    x    x    x  
   0% |
      |___________________
        0%  33%   66%  100%
```

and a non-flat linear graph

```
 100% |                     x
  75% |                x
  50% |           x     
  25% |      x
   0% | x
      |________________________
        0%  25%  50%  75% 100%
```

Comment: Piecewise constant is probably what you're looking for. That means that it is constant for various pieces, but the constants may be different.

Comment: I'd call it a step function, or a rounding function (except you're a bit less forgiving and round $50\%$ down to $0\%$).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A [piecewise constant function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Step_function) (a.k.a step function) is one possibility for any graph that is constant (flat) on different pieces.

You may also be interested in [characteristic functions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Indicator_function) (a.k.a. indicator functions).

Comment: @max pleaner. Another term you may be interested in is "piece-wise linear".